# Generating distrubted amount of records

Tags: sql, oracle, parent-child, distributed

I have some code that is generating parent and a random number of child records for each parent. I want there to 5 or more child records for each parent and less than 20.

I ran this several times and I seem to be getting none or very few child records in the range of 5-13.

Can someone please explain how I can get a more distributed value of child records.

If you run the last query below you will see there are no count(*) or very few for from the values 6-15.

No doubt I have a problem with my logic but I can't seem to find it. I'm also open to any new code that accomplishes the same task and produces a distributed amount of child records with an INSERT all statement.

My goal is to generate a huge amount of testing data to examine the application queries. For now I'm only generating 30 days worth.

```
CREATE TABLE emp_info
(
 empid   INTEGER,
 empname VARCHAR2(50)
);

CREATE TABLE  emp_attendance    
(
 empid      INTEGER,
 start_date DATE,
 end_date   DATE
);

INSERT ALL 
  -- WHEN rn=1 insert the parent record.
  -- 1 will always =1 always insert a
  -- child record.
  WHEN rn = 1 then into emp_info   (empid, empname) values (id, name)
  WHEN  1 = 1 then into emp_attendance (empid, start_date, end_date) 
  VALUES(id, d1, d1 + DBMS_RANDOM.value (0, .75))
SELECT *
  FROM 
  (
    -- get the highest empid as start
    -- so this can be run more than once.
    -- if never run before start WITH 0.

    WITH t AS ( SELECT nvl(max(empid), 0) maxid FROM emp_info )
    SELECT CEIL(maxid + level/20) id,
      CASE MOD(maxid + level, 20) WHEN 1 THEN 1 END rn, 
      -- create an alpha name from 3-15
      -- characters in length.
     DBMS_RANDOM.string('U', DBMS_RANDOM.value(3, 15)) name, 
    -- set the start date any where from
    -- today + 30 days
    TRUNC(sysdate) + DBMS_RANDOM.value (1, 30) d1,      
    CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CEIL(maxid + level/20) ORDER BY level) > 5 THEN
     -- Ensure there is a minimum of
     -- 5 child and a max of 20 records 
       -- for each parent.
        --
       -- Exclude first 5 records and then  
       -- for 6-20 records, generating 
      -- random number between 5-20. 
      -- We can then compare with any 
        -- number between 5-20 so that it 
       -- can give us any number of 
       -- records.
          DBMS_RANDOM.value(5, 20) ELSE 5 END AS random_val 
         FROM t   
      CONNECT BY level <= 20 * 1000
 )  
 WHERE random_val <= 19;
 -- why is this where clause neeed?

SELECT empid, COUNT(*) 
  FROM emp_attendance
 GROUP BY empid 
 ORDER BY empid; 


EMPID    COUNT(*)
1        20
2        20
3        20
4        18
5        19
6        20
7        20
8        19
9        20
10       20   
11       19
……
50       20
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should get you going.

```
SQL> with
  2    emps as
  3      ( select level empid, dbms_random.value(5,20) children from dual connect by level <= 20 ),
  4    empatt as
  5      ( select e.empid , x.start_date, x.start_date+dbms_random.value(0,0.75) end_date
  6        from emps e,
  7             lateral(
  8               select
  9                 trunc(sysdate)+dbms_random.value(1,30) start_date
 10               from dual
 11               connect by level <= e.children
 12               ) x
 13       )
 14  select empid, count(*)
 15  from empatt
 16  group by empid
 17  order by 1;

     EMPID   COUNT(*)
---------- ----------
         1          5
         2         14
         3         17
         4          6
         5         10
         6         18
         7         12
         8         13
         9         16
        10         11
        11          7
        12         14
        13          7
        14          7
        15          7
        16         13
        17         18
        18          9
        19          9
        20         12
```

Comment: Connor thanks for the response. I am anxious to look into the lateral command

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT ALL

WHEN  attendid = 1

THEN INTO emp_info (empid, empname)  VALUES

(empid, dbms_random.string ( 'U',                dbms_random.value (3, 15))                        

)

WHEN  attendid  <= attend_cnt

THEN INTO  emp_attendance (empid, start_date, end_date) VALUES

(empid, start_date, start_date + dbms_random.value (0, .75))

WITH    got_maxid   AS

(

SELECT  NVL (MAX (empid), 0)  AS maxid

FROM    emp_info

)

,    new_emps    AS

(

SELECT  maxid + CEIL (LEVEL / 50)  AS empid

,       MOD (LEVEL, 50) + 1        AS attendid,

      CASE
          WHEN  MOD (LEVEL, 50) = 0
            THEN  dbms_random.value (5, 50+ 1)

        END   AS attend_cnt0
FROM    got_maxid
CONNECT BY  LEVEL <= 2000
   )

SELECT    n.*,

  MIN (attend_cnt0) OVER (PARTITION BY empid)  AS attend_cnt,
   TRUNC (SYSDATE) + dbms_random.value (5, 30)  AS start_date

FROM      new_emps  n;
```